# How do you calculate proportions of a randomly generated dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

I'm trying to work out the proportions of each value in a dataframe I have generated randomly.
The dataframe is made up of categorical values.

I have 8 columns (breeds of dog) & 3 possible outputs (colours black, white & brown). I've generated a random dataset of 50,000 outputs (or rows) of data under each column.

I'd like to verify the proportions of, for example, black Labradors, white Labradors, brown Labradors (shown in first column), & also black poodles, white poodles, brown poodles (shown in second column).

I've tried `prop.table()`; however this doesn't work for categorical data. Calculating the no. of each output per column using `table()`, then using `prop.table()` works, but I'd like to shorten the steps in the code required to do this as there must be a more efficient way...?

Here is what I have so far...

```r
# Create eight arbitrary columns (for example, dog breeds)
my_col <- c("Poodle", "Labrador", "Pug", "Chihuahua", "Collie", "Shitzu", "Bulldog", "Lurcher")
# Create three arbitrary levels for columns (for example, colours)
my_lev <- c("brown", "black", "white")
# Create randomly generated dataset
df <- data.frame(replicate(length(my_col), sample(my_lev, 50000, replace = TRUE)))
#and then set the names by: 
names(df) <- my_col
# Check dataframe
df
# b) Verify that the proportions of each value are similar for each of the eight columns.
prop.table(table(sample(df, size = 50000, replace = TRUE)))
poodle_number <- table(df$Poodle)
poodle_prop <- prop.table(poodle_number)
```

Comment: could we have a [mre] please?  Are you looking for some combination of `table()` (tabulate proportions) and `apply()` (use a function on multiple columns)?   Or just `sum(x[,1]=="green") > sum(x[,-1]=="green")`?  A worked example on a really small example data set (say, only 4 rows & 3 columns) would help.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes ofcourse. I have 8 columns (breeds of dog) & 3 possible outputs (colours black, white & brown). I've generated a random dataset of 50,000 outputs (or rows) of data under each column. I'd like to verify the proportions of, for example, black labradors, white labradors, brown labradors (shown in 1st column), &also black poodles, white poodles, brown poodles (shown in 2nd column). I've tried prop.table however this doesnt work for categorical data. Calculating the no. of each output per column using table(), then using prop.table() on this works, but I'd like to shorten the steps.

Comment: Your description makes it much clearer. Could you (1) include this description in your question and (2) if possible, include a small bit of code that would simulate data that look like yours (you could simplify, e.g. by including only three breeds)?  Having example data makes it much easier to answer/test out potential answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually easier if you are willing to convert your data (at least temporarily) to **long format**, for example:

Convert to long format (using `tidy::pivot_longer()` but there are a variety of ways of doing this if you're tidyverse-averse):

```r
dflong <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df,cols=my_col,names_to="breed",values_to="color")
```

The data now look like this:

```r
> dflong
# A tibble: 400,000 x 2
   breed     color
   <chr>     <chr>
 1 Poodle    black
 2 Labrador  brown
 3 Pug       white
```

Now you can cross-tabulate in one line: `margin=1` specifies that we want to compute proportions across rows of the tables (color within breed):

```r
with(dflong,prop.table(table(breed,color),margin=1))
```

```
           color
breed         black   brown   white
  Bulldog   0.33170 0.33322 0.33508
  Chihuahua 0.32966 0.33622 0.33412
  Collie    0.33254 0.33230 0.33516
  Labrador  0.33560 0.33098 0.33342
  Lurcher   0.33322 0.33282 0.33396
  Poodle    0.33252 0.33434 0.33314
  Pug       0.33138 0.33624 0.33238
  Shitzu    0.33328 0.33414 0.33258
```

This could also be done in tidyverse (specifically using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages):

```r
(dflong 
   %>% count(breed,color) 
   %>% group_by(breed) 
   %>% mutate(n=n/sum(n)) 
   %>% pivot_wider(names_from=color,values_from=n)
)
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this without switching to long format:

```r
apply(df,2,function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

(transpose this with `t()` if you want output that looks the same as the solutions above).  This version leaves the results in the same breed order as in your original data frame rather than alphabetizing the breeds ...

Comment: This is great, thanks Ben! :D